# EF Query Model Tutorial link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Facing problem with every fetch i want to make using EF Query model.Place here few links from where i can grab EF Query model concepts in short time. i.e how to query your MODEL/EDM.
**NEED SOLUTION** ::
I have a method in my controller having primary key as parameter say 
`public action(int id)`
now i want to fetch a list from table2(one to many relationship b/w table1 with primary key to table2 with foreign key) by matching that primary key with foreign key.
`(from data in db.table2
                        where package.id==id
                         select package)`
I want to do this but in a neater terms(by using LINQ to ENTITY objects).

Comment: No offense but where did you search for solution so far? Did you hear about Google? Moreover did you hear about MSDN (it provides documentation to whole .NET framework)? If you need to learn whole concepts and you are not able to search on Internet buy a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854248/entity-framework-4-0-book-recommendations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will do:

```
 var linqResult = Context.CreateObjectSet<TSecondary>()
                   .Where(secondary=>secondary.ParentID == id);
```

Comment: Guys i need a link from where i can learn these concepts in details any help ll,b appreciated